# Strategy for Rest API Authentication and How to Store Tokens on Client Applications

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, passport.js, refresh-token

I'm setting up a Rest API for both native (mobile apps) and browser-based applications (react etc.). I'm using `express.js` and `passport.js` with LocalStrategy and JwtStrategy.

I've researched about this topic and there are a lot of different conversations or tutorials. Most of the tutorials just creates an access token and never talks about how to refresh it. And a lot of others just uses providers like `Okta` or `Auth0`. I don't want to reinvent the wheel but I think I should be able to create a simple authentication mechanism.

My current process is like this;
* Create an access and refresh token on login. Return them as response.
* Client stores it. In react I use `localStorage` to store the tokens.
* Add `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` header to requests.
* When the `access_token` expires, get new tokens by using the current `refresh_token`.

I'm storing refresh tokens to DB on the server. So, a users can track all of their current sessions or an admin can invoke them when there is a security issue.

After a lot of research I see that there is a big disagreement on either using `localStorage` to store tokens on the browser, or return tokens as `httpOnly` cookies.

And when I examined  some popular websites I saw that, websites like Facebook, Github, Youtube, 9gag use cookies to keep you signed in. They don't send an `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` header. There are mainly information about UI states in the localStorage. But when you delete the `SID` cookie, all of them logs you out. Are they using session-based authentication?

When you login to TMDb (the movie database), it sets 2 cookies named as `access_token` (which is just a JWT) and `session`. I guess this is an implementation which the server returns the access token and some sort of a "persistance" information (session) as cookies.

Firebase (one of my favorites about this topic) just stores both the access and refresh token to `localStorage`. It actually uses `indexedDB` but I've read it falls back to localStorage when it can't use indexedDB.

But OWASP recommends that "browser-based applications should never retrieve a refresh token". I guess this means when the access token is expired, authorization server should be checked to see if there is still a session going on and then a new access token is retrieved. (Silent renew)

The only exception that I've seen is Azure Portal. It sends bearer tokens in the `Authorization` header. It stores the refresh token in the `localStorage`. And a lot of "security sensitive" corporations use it to deploy/maintain their applications or databases etc.

So, Firebase and Azure Portal are examples to access/refresh tokens saved to localStorage on the browser. TMDb is an example to getting tokens in `httpOnly` cookies. And Facebook, Youtube etc. are using some sort of authentication mechanism that I couldn't understand. Cookies and sessions I think?

Returning access and refresh tokens to both native and browser-based applications has a really simple logic and implementation. Storing them in localStorage always felt like it is a big risk. But I didn't want to set cookies for web applications and return JSON response for mobile applications. I felt like they should be the same. And after seeing examples like Firebase and Azure Portal, I don't feel like it is that much wrong.

But is it really safe even if there are a lot of disagreement and articles about this? And even if Firebase and Azure Portal are good examples to this strategy, why are websites like Facebook, 9gag, Youtube mainly use cookies (and sessions I think) for authentication?

I know this is a big topic. I know there may be a lot of different approaches. But I think I need some sort of a cornerstone idea to implement authentication for simple applications.

Comment: What did you went with? Especially how long you keep refresh tokens? What do you do when a user uses login in 500 new private windows and closes it without logout? Have 500 refresh tokens in the database for that user?

Comment: I return an access token (expires in 1 hour), and a refresh token (expires in 1 week). When a request is being made, it first checks if the access token is still valid. If it is passed it's expiration time or if it will be expired in next 5 minutes, I send refresh token to the /refresh-token endpoint in request body. It validates the refresh token, swaps the current refresh token with a new one, updates the database table that holds the userId with refresh tokens. Generates a new access token and returns both the access and the refresh token.

Comment: Then the client stores them to local storage and continues the current request(s). Key point is, pausing the request(s) which the client is making and calling the /refresh-token endpoint only once. You can use an axios interceptor, redux-observable (or simply rxjs) etc. It's mostly the hardest part for me. But you can find examples with similar approaches.
You can also restrict the refresh token count of a user. For example, when a user logs in and if there are already 5 refresh token in the db, you can delete the oldest one, and insert the new one.

Comment: I'd also recommend you to really consider using traditional sessions. The flow I'm telling you is simply trying to reinvent the wheel from scratch. Sessions already solve a lot of these problems and they are around since the very early days of the web applications. 
This is a really good explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdJ0wFi1Jyo
There are a lot of different opinions. A lot of ups and downs about them. But I would recommend you to take the simplest way and just focus on your productivity and other features. I get stuck about authentication a lot of times and it's really bad.

Comment: But when do you clear the tokens out of the database? What if I hit your refresh-token endpoint thousands of times?

Comment: You can run a scheduled job (like cron) to clear expired tokens from db every 24 hours and if you hit the refresh token endpoint that much, there would still be 5 active tokens for your userId, because everytime a user logs in and if there are already 5 tokens for that user, you would just delete the oldest one and insert the new one. You may think like, a user can only have 5 active sessions. You can also use things like rate limiting or check if a user is abusing the token endpoint and if so, ban the user temporarily or infinitely.

Comment: You can also add rules like "a user can only create 10 session each day". So when the user tries to login for the 11th time, you simply restrict access. You can add any kind of security rule to this flow.

Comment: I guess I'll go with that. Max 5 tokens per "client_id". Either web or mobile. Will just be confusing if you really open 5 private windows and are logged out of the main window next time you try to access the website.